# Display image from directory using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, scripting

I'm currently learning the basics of web development, but one thing I haven't encountered a solution for yet is getting an image from a directory using jQuery.
If I have a checkbox defined as follows...

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox">
```

... how can I get an image from a directory, and display it in a `<div>` based on the current state of the checkbox (without messing with the HTML)? What I've found so far is this, but this is simply for showing the existing contents of a `<div>`, correct?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#check').click(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
            ("div").show();
        }
    });
});
```

The reason I don't want to touch the HTML is that I want to gain a more in-depth understanding of the more powerful functions of jQuery (I don't want to build bad habits), but this is proving to be a difficult thing to do on my own. I'd really appreciate any help (or just some hints)!

tl;dr: Checked box = image, unchecked = no image. jQuery only because of reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can(assuming the div is present)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //create a reference to the div which can be reused later
    var $div = $('div'),
        $img;
    $('#check').change(function () {
        //set the display status of the div based on checked state of the checkbox
        $div.toggle(this.checked);
        if (this.checked) {
            //if it is checked and the img is not present create one
            if (!$img) {
                $img = $('<img />', {
                    src: '//placehold.it/64/00ff00'
                }).appendTo($div);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/78cfpyt9/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're HTML looks like this:

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox">
<div class="image-to-show-and-hide"><img id="image-to-place" /></div>
```

You can make your jQuery look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#check').click(function(){
    // Avoiding the negation where possible can make code a easier to read.
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      // Show the div with the specified class:
      $(".image-to-show-and-hide").show();
      // And show the image by filling its "src" attribute.
      $("#image-to-place").attr("src","http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg");
    }
    else {
      // Otherwise, hide the div.
      $(".image-to-show-and-hide").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9gdpdLmb/1/